# cocos2d-x DrawNode setConteneSize not work properly

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I want to draw a dot on screen via DrawNode drawDot function, after I setContentSize I noticed the BoundingBox of this dot is not right, the dot is not the inscribed circle of boundingBox.(effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY8BV.png))

the effect I want is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXEjv.png)

Here are my codes:

```
void TouchingDot::setDot()
{
    int x = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().width / 2;
    int y = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().height / 2;
    Vec2 position(x,y);
    setPosition(position);
    drawDot(Vec2(0,0), dotR, Color4F::RED);
    setContentSize(Size(radius * 2, radius * 2));
}
```

I tried using `setAnchorPoint()` but is not change anything.